# Strange thing with C++ memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management

Consider the output of this code:

```
char A = 'a';
char B[] = "b";
cout<<&A;
```

It outputs "ab" (the concatenation of `A` and `B`) and I wonder why. Please, explain me this.

Comment: `cout` doesn't exist in C. Don't spam tags.

Comment: What you have is undefined behavior. Why this happens can be explained, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: The way of printing the output does not matter there. It remains a C problem, while the question is about memory management both of C and C++.

Comment: @qtug - No it doesn't remain a C problem. The C standard doesn't specify `cout`, nor is your construct legal C code. How it works is specified by the C++ standard. If you cared about C, you should have posted valid C code.

Comment: cast to void if you want to print the address: `std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(&A);`

Comment: And you should know that C and C++ can manage memory differently. Different specifications means different languages.

Comment: @qtug  Take into account that you can ask your questions in Russian SO at http://ru.stackoverflow.com and there you will be told about strings.:)

Answer (score 15):

Because `&A` is a `char *`. A string, represented by a `char *`, is required to have a `'\0'` terminating byte.

`&A` points to a single `char`, without a following `'\0'`. As such, attempting to print this text string results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - cast to `void*`. Which is kinda the correct way to use the `%p` for stdio, as well.

Answer (score 4):

You got an unexpected result because the `operator <<` for objects of type `char *` is overloaded such a way that it outputs strings pointed to by pointers of the type `char *`.

It seems that your compiler placed the array `B` after the character `A` and in the memory they look like one string.

```
'a' 'b' '\0'
|   |
A   B
```

(It is unspecified in the C++ Standard whether `A` will precede  `B` or `B` will precede `A` in the memory and whether there will be a gap due to padding bytes between the objects.)

If you want to output the address of the object A you should write for example

```
cout<< ( void * )&A;
```

or

```
cout<< ( const void * )&A;
```

or either ,like

```
cout<< static_cast<void *>( &A );
```

or like

```
cout<< static_cast<const void *>( &A );
```

It is unimportant whether the `const` qualifier will be specified for the pointer to a non-constant object because. It will be implicitly converted to the type `const void *` in the operator

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(const void* p);
```

Comment: I liked the consideration of possible purpose of the code, and how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why

Because the stream insertion operator requires that any character pointer passed to it must point to a null terminated character string. The pointer passed to `cout` points to `A` which is not a null terminated character string. Since the pre-conditions (requirements) of the operation were not satisfied, the behaviour is undefined.

---

There are two relevant overloads for insertion operator (I've simplified away the template details, and the fact the one of these is a member overload, and the other is not):

```
ostream& operator<< (const void*);
ostream& operator<< (const char*);
```

All other pointers implicitly convert to `void*` and use the former overload and the pointer is outputed as a memory address. But the latter is favoured overload for character pointers, and the argument is required to be a null terminated string.

So, because a character pointer is interpreted as null terminated string, the naïve attempt to print the address of a character does not work. The solution: Cast the pointer to `void*` explicitly before passing to the stream.

The streams have been designed this way, in order to conveniently support null terminated strings, such as string literals which were considered to be (and are) streamed more typically than addresses. For example, it is convenient that `std::cout << "Hello World!";`. Prints "Hello World" instead of a memory address where the string literal is located.

Answer (score 1):

`cout` expects the `char*` parameter to point to a zero terminated string. But `&A` isn't zero terminated, so the precondition fails and this leads to undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior cannot really be explained, because the standard allows *anything* to happen. Displaying some more characters is one possible result. As is crashing. Or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compiler-dependent behavior. Often, A nad B will be allocated one after the other on the stack. Taking the address of A will look like the zero-terminated string "ab". **Don't do this!** You rely on the stack frame layout the compiler is constructing.

Answer (score 0):

because your char is not null terminated.
The behavior for this will UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler has placed string comprising 'b' and '\0' immediately after character 'a' so once you've printed your **A** character as a string it found 'a', followed by 'b' followed by '\0' hence you have printed 'ab'